# Route path contain data that would be fetched into beforeRouteEnter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, routeparams

In my router there is a dynamic Route that I need to set the last part of its path after the data is fetched from the store call in beforeRouteEnter

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
if(to.params.categoryId) {
  next(vm => {
    store.dispatch('getSearchResults', to.params)
      .then(res => {
        let category = res.data.categories.find(cat => cat.id == to.params.categoryId);
        to.params.CName = category.name;
        // to.path = to.path + `/${category.name}`;
        console.log(to)
      }).catch(err => false)
  })
}else next();
```

the Route:

```
{
  path: 'directory/bc-:categoryId(\\d+)?/:CName?',
  name: 'SearchResults',
  component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "listing" */ '../views/SearchResults.vue')
},
```

I need to change the CName in the Route to category.name from the data so that the route finally shows the category name after the Id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a route with 2 children - one that will dispatch the Vuex action and then go to the other child.

```
{
  path: 'directory/bc-:categoryId(\\d+)?',
  name: 'SearchResultsParent',
  redirect:
  {
    name: 'SearchResultsFetch',
  },
  component: WrapperComponent,
  children:
  [
    {
      path: '',
      name: 'SearchResultsFetch',
      component: FetchSearchResults,
    },
    {
      path: ':CName',
      name: 'SearchResultsList',
      component: ShowSearchResults,
    },
  ]
}
```

```html
// WrapperComponent.vue
<template>
  ....
  <router-view />
  ....
</template>
```

```html
// FetchSearchResults.vue
<script>
export default
{
  created()
  {
    this.fetchData();
  },
  beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next)
  {
    this.fetchData();
    next();
  },
  methods:
  {
    fetchData()
    {
      store.dispatch('getSearchResults', this.$route.params)
      .then(res => {
        let category = res.data.categories.find(cat => cat.id == this.route.params.categoryId);
        this.$router.push({
          name: 'SearchResultsList',
          params:
          {
            categoryId: this.$route.params.categoryId,
            CName: category.name,
          }
        });
      }).catch(err => false)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: one small problem happened with me, when I refresh the page it gets stuck and doesnt fetch the data on created.

Comment: thank you so much for the help, there was another problem in my WrapperComponent too that blocked the router-view from showing.